# ActionView::Base#lookup_context view_renderer is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was running my rails server without any issues until I attempted to import more data into my database (MySql). Now any view that I try to load gets the following error:

`ActionView::Base#lookup_context delegated to view_renderer.lookup_context, but view_renderer is nil: #<#<Class:0x007f7a985c57a0>:0x007f7a9850a9c8 @virtual_path=nil, @output_buffer=nil>`

I have tried resetting the server and restarting the machine running the server, but I cannot find anyone with a similar problem after a couple hours of searching. I have also attached the Full Trace below:

```
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/base.rb:194:in `rescue in lookup_context'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/base.rb:191:in `lookup_context'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:165:in `refresh'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:318:in `handle_render_error'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:148:in `rescue in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/local/ANT/silbers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:24:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3399700574629612850__process_action__549665627831877268__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1806545944124118878__call__2361770013248114262__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/local/ANT/silbers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/local/ANT/silbers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/local/ANT/silbers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
def index
 @sessions = Session.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).search(params[:search])
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html  #index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @sessions }
  end
end
```

Comment: Please answer all 4 questions: How did you import the data? Are you sure there were no other changes that kicked in with some restart, etc? Does this happen on every request? Can you paste `sessions_controller.rb`?

Comment: I imported the data using a rake tast that parses JSON and adds the data to the MySQL server this way. There are no changes that I'm aware of...I have attempted to update my gems but the issue still persists. This happens on every request that involves HTML...json calls render fine. I will edit the above post to show my def index from sessions_controller.rb

Comment: Do you have a db backup so you could revert it to pre-import state?

Comment: I have made a backup and started with a fresh database and still have the same error.

Comment: I don't belive it may have been caused by any change in db. If you use git or other scm try going back a few versions and see if problem persists.